# How to get data to my Angular page with PHP?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the data from mysql in my Angularjs page and I am using PHP as my server side language. I am not able to get the data in my page, however I got the data from my PHP file. And if you have some alternative of it please tell me.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
   <h2>here is the info</h2>
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">

    <td>{{country.Empno}}</td>
    <td>{{country.Ename}}</td>
    <td>{{country.Job}}</td>
    <td>{{country.Hiredate}}</td>
    <td>{{country.Salary}}</td>

    </tr>
     </table>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'one.php'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // Store response data
  $scope.country = response.data;
 });
}]);
 </script>
</html>
```

here is the one.php file

```js
 <?php
 $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","vikash","jarvis");
 if($link==false){
  die("you are not connected to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 
 $query="SELECT * FROM emp";
$data=array();
 if($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
 {
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  {
  
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    $data[]=array("Empno"=>$row['empno'],"Ename"=>$row['ename'],"Job"=>$row['job'],"Hiredate"=>['hiredate'],"Salary"=>['sal']);
    
   }
  }
  else
  {
   echo "no records are matching";
  }

 }
 else
 {
  die("could not able to execue the command ".mysqli_error($link));
 }


echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($link);
  ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you make a get request in a browser to your `one.php`? Show the output.

Comment: It display all the data from the database in the json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused between absolute file paths and internet addresses. `one.php` is not a URL, it is a system file path.

You need to serve your `one.php` file via a webserver which will give is an address like `http://localhost/one.php` and then use that as your URL in your angularJS code.

This is because you are using angular's `$http` module, which is designed for IP (Internet Protocol). It is not designed for system file access.

Comment: I have also tried this but there is no output in my page.

Comment: If there is no output on your page then your problem has nothing to do with AngularJS. When you say "I have tried this"... what `exactly` have you tried? You need to get your PHP code working before you worry about the AngularJS. What does your web server's error logs say?

Comment: Try this... replace your `one.php` file's contents with this: `<?php echo 'hello world';` and then try browse to it again and tell me what output you get on your page.

Comment: Sir my php code is working fine, it is showing all the data which is fetched from database and it  is in json format. I have no output in angularjs page that is my problem.

Comment: i have put the <?php echo 'hello world';?> as you said, but there is No output sir!

Comment: Show us the URL

Comment: i have done a silly mistake, it is working now. Anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: "Thanks" is best indicated by using vote buttons on Stackoverflow. Or accepting an answer. Better yet, submit your own answer. Just leaving it hanging like you've done is a 'no-no' as it does not contribute to the platform. Be a giver, not just a taker.